# Seeking mnemonic for the order of the Pesach Seder

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

The Passover Seder is long and has lots of steps. Sometimes I get confused what comes next!

I'm looking for a mnemonic (perhaps poetic?) to use to help remember the order of the different steps. Do you know of any that have been used in the past?

Comment: Holy salad breaks the news: a meal in Sing-Sing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some more simple ones:

1. גפן. קידוש. [נר. הבדלה.] זמן. נטילת.
   ירקות. אדטה. וטבל. בצע. עניא. כסא. ונשתנה. נטילת. שלימה מוציא. ופרוס אכילת
   עמה. חסא. מרור. טבל. כרך. וסעד. בצוע. מפטיר. ונוטל. שלישי למזון ורביעי להלל.‏ ([Machzor Vitri](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14643&st=&pgnum=502&hilite=))
2. קר״י חכמ״ה בי״ן המל״ך אמ״ן = קדוש רחיצה ירקות. חולק כהא מזוג הגדה. ברכת יין נטילה. המוציא מצה לטיף כריכה. אפיקומן מים נברך.‏ ([Mahari Ovarnik](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15009&st=&pgnum=95&hilite=))
3. קנ״ך יהנ״ה ממ״ך שמ״ה = קידוש נטילה כרפס. יחץ הגדה נטילה המוציא. מצה מרור כריכה. שמורה מזון הלל. ‏ ([Abudirham](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=124))
4. קדש ותתקדש טבול ופרוס. ודרשת רחץ ובצע וחוק מצה שמור. מרור אכול וכורך ולחם סתרך. ומזונך על כל כוס יהללך גמור.‏ ([Abudirham](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=124))
5. יקדש יטהר וכרפס וחצה. ודורש ונוטל ללחם ומצה. ומרור וכורך ואוכל פרוסה. ונקי יזמן יהלל בדיצה.‏  ([Abudirham](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=124))
6. קדש ורחץ. כרפס יחץ. מגיד רחצ[ה]. מוציא מצה. מרור כורך. שלחן עורך. צפון ברך. הלל נרצה. ‏ ([Shmuel of Falaise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_ben_Solomon_of_Falaise))
7. קדוש ידי אדם וטבול בצעו. יגיד בגפן יד יציאת מצה. מרור וטבול גם כריכה סעוד. מצה ידי מזון והלל יצא.‏ ([Abudirham](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=124))
8. בורא קדש החייך ונטול ירק לחמא רזון. ידך תוציא מצה מרור וכרוך ושבע אפיק מזון.‏ (Machzor Benei Roma)
9. קדש ורחץ. כרפס יחץ. מגיד רחצה. מוציא מצה. מרור כורך. שלחן עורך. צפון נוטל. ברך. הלל נרצה.‏ (Maharach Or Zarua 21)
10. קדש ורחץ. כרפס יחץ. מגיד רחצה. מוציא מצה. מרור כורך. שלחן עורך. טמון רחץ. ברך הלל. נרצה.‏ (Minhagim (Chidlik))
11. .קדוש נטול מור. שבר לכחוש לחמי .נסי גאל ידך. תצא סמוך עני
    .ארר חזיר זכרו. סועד שבור שוטמי. מי פרנסה תן. כוס אעריץ קוני‏ ([Etz Chayim](http://web.archive.org/web/20090623095915/http://shituf.piyut.org.il/story/1503))
12. .יקר גפני תקדש חי ונטל טרפי ארצי. עקור מצה טמון לוחמי לאות כרמך ביד תוציא. באוכלי מר ביחד חוס זכור מקדש סעוד לחצי.‏ ([Rav Yaakov](http://web.archive.org/web/20090623095915/http://shituf.piyut.org.il/story/1503))

(6 seems quite popular nowadays)

Comment: What's אדטה in the first one?  Is it a typo for אדמה?  Also what's חסא?

Comment: @Heshy ya should be adama, chasa is lettuce

Comment: Ah interesting, so did they eat multiple kinds of maror as a separate step?

Comment: @Heshy i dont think so. did they also eat multiple vegetables for karpas? 'maror' in the poem is the blessing, 'chasa' is the food. just like yerakot adama.

Comment: My Haggadah has some different Nusachos from some of these. For #11 it has קדוש נטול מור עובר, לכחוש לחמי נסי גאל, ידך תינא סמוך עני, ארר חזיר זכרו סועד, שבור שוטמי מי פרנסה, תן כוס מעריץ קוני. For #8 it sticks in וטמון before לחמא רזון. For #1 it has גפן, קידוש, [נר, הבדיל], זמן, נטילה, יקרות אדמה טובל...נטילה, שלימה מוציא, ופרוס אכילת מצה, עמה חסא מרור טבל...בשובע מפטיר. For #4 it concludes על כוס יהללך גמור. For #3 it reads יהנה as יבצע הגדה נטילה המוציא (and it ascribes it to R' Shmuel son of R' Meshulam Yaroni, though they say the Avudraham, among others, quotes it).

Answer (score 4):

The expanded Oz V'hadar Mesivta Haggadah (p. 384-386) brings eighteen different mnemonics and poems. Below I quote the ones DoubleAA didn't already quote in [his answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81655/):

1. ברא קדיש חיים נטל ירק, נטמן לחם ידי מציאתו, מצא במרירות בריכתו, שובע מזונותיו אחרי פק ה׳.‏ (R' Shlomo Chazzan of Onkona(?))
2. קדש בכוס ראשון, ובירק גנך טבל, והגדה בכוס שני אמור. ברך עלי לחם, ועל מצה ועל מרור, ובכריכה דבר הלל גמור. ואכול סעודתך ומצתך, ופן תפטיר לאחריה אפיקומן שמור. וכוס שלישי על מזונך צורך ברך, וברביעי זכור הלל גמור. לחי בציון תעשה את פסחך, בעלות מקום הנעצוץ קנה ומור.‏ (Avudraham)
3. זכור היום ויד נקה לכרפס, פתות פתים ותדרוש כהלכה. ושנית טול לברך כפרוסה, אכול מצה שמורה וערוכה. ומרור תכרוך יחד במצה, כמו הלל ואל תאמר ברכה. ונחת שולחנך חן תמלא, חלוק מצה בתוך מפה כרוכה. עלי מזון תברך צור תהלל. ואם תצמא קרא שירה נסוכה. שכב בטח ואל תירא ותחת, הלא מרפא לליל זה וארוכה.‏ (Some manuscripts of Avudraham)
4. אמור נוטל, יטבול יחלק, צלצל חטא, קבץ בצעם. נמרר אכרך, לסעד אפיק, חמד דבר, בתהלות עם.‏ (R' Yitzchak Ibn Elachadav; the initials read אני יצחק אבן אלאחדב)

I know the purpose of this exercise is to have something shorter so it's easy to remember the order of the Seder, but here's some lengthier ones anyhow.

5. על הגפן קדוש בזמנה,‏
   במוצאי שבת יקנה״ז סימנה,‏
   ולאחריו מעין שלש טעונה,‏
   וידיו ירחץ ויברך כתקנה.‏
   אדמה בטבול ברכה הגונה,‏
   ובוצע שניה למשמרת נתונה,‏
   וירום קערה ורון בקנה (נ״א וירון ברנה),‏
   הא לחמא דאכלו אבהתנא.‏
   ומוזג שני במה נשתנה,‏
   ברכת היין לבסוף אינה,‏
   נוטל ובוצע על הראשונה,‏
   וכורך לתחתונה שהיא עליונה (נ״א וכורך השניה שהיא תחתונה).‏
   כזית מרור בחרוסת ישקענה,‏
   מצות ומרורים כזית רעננה,‏
   לא יהיה להם זכרון עם שיהיו לאחרונה.‏
   (Maharam of Rothenburg)
6. לבל ימוט נצח, כלל סדר פסח, והיה על מצח, לאות ולמזכרת.‏
   אסדר לקוטיו, כלליו ופרטיו, ואשקול משפטיו, בשיר על מחברת.‏
   תחלה ובראשו, יקדש קדושו, בראשון מכוסו לגפן אדרת.‏
   וידיו בכלי לצורך טבולי, יהי נוטל בכלי, ברכה נאמרת.‏
   ויטבול כרפס בחומץ, ובראשו יברך אל עושו, ופוטר אחרת.‏
   ולשנים יבצע למצה של אמצע, ומחציה תצנע במפה משמרת.‏
   והגדה ישנה, בכוס שני ישנה, ואל שואל יענה תשובה נסברת.‏
   ויטול כהלכה נטילה בברכה להמוציא ככה ומצה חוברת.‏
   במרור יתעשת לטבל בחרוסת, והכריכה נעשית במצה וחזרת.‏
   ויאכל מאכלו, והצפון אצלו, והשלישי כוס לו ברכה נגמרת.‏
   בכוס רביעי להלל אל רועי, בחלל שעשועי להוד ולתפארת.‏
   (R' Chaim Banebashti in Pesach Me'ovin, citing his brother)
7. שפשף לוטול מקודם הקידוש,‏
   ברכת נטילה מיחו הגאונים,‏
   רוב רביעית ישתה חירות ירמז,‏
   אדמה לטבול לברת ונפשות רבות,‏
   ירום אמצעי שלימה לחציה יעשה טמון,‏
   הא נהמא קול רם אקרעה,‏
   שנית למזוג מצות הרחק,‏
   רביא בנשתנה ישאל,‏
   יגיד צריך חיזור קודם,‏
   שירה הלל וברך אגאולה,‏
   הגפן מברך,‏
   מים צרופים יברך אראשונה מוציא,‏
   חבירים יאחז דברי המצה,‏
   זכור והסב באכלך רענן,‏
   מרור יברך זכור השעבור,‏
   לטובול חרוסת כריכה יזכור מעשה אבות,‏
   הוצא מטמין,‏
   שלישית כראשונה ימלא למזון,‏
   ומברך הבעל מדות חכמים כוס ימלא מלסיים,‏
   ישפוך דם עממיו וישפוך,‏
   יגמור בהלל יסיים נשמת,‏
   חתום ישתבח דיינו ומשלש תברך,‏
   ולא תשתה עוד לרות ותנעים מזמורים ותספר תקפו,‏
   ואם רוה זעירא יסולק,‏
   ישתה גדול לכוס החמישי,‏
   חתום זכור קדוש.‏
   (Maharshal; the initials read שלמה בן מהר״ר יחיאל לוריא שליט הנקרא שלמה רב יצחק שהוא הממציא מחידה זו ברמיזה לחכימא המשכיל והמחכים ידע ויבין חידות ותעלומות ורזי יגלה חז״ק)
8. **י**קדש בכוס ישועות ושמחה,‏
   לסדר זמני ששון ומועדי שמחה,‏
   ואם יבא במוצאי מנוחה,‏
   נר והבדלה לפני זמן להפציחה,‏
   והשתיה כדת כדרך חרות והנחה,‏
   יטול ידיו כהלכה בלי צוחה,‏
   ירקות שאין מזכירים אנחה,‏
   בלי שעור זאת הלקיחה,‏
   בברכת בורא תנובה וצמיחה,‏
   וטובל בחומץ או במיא דילחא,‏
   חלה תיכונה לשתים לפלחה,‏
   מחציתה צרורה עד אחר ארוחה,‏
   ומחצית בין השתים להניחה,‏
   לברכת חררה דלא תפחה,‏
   בפצותו הא לחמא שלא נעשה למשחה,‏
   יגביה בקערה בחדוה בלי גניחה.‏
   **ש**ני ימזוג בשואלו מה נשתנה,‏
   מן השלחן יעקור קערה מכנה,‏
   להחזירו בפתחו האגדה ברננה,‏
   מרים מצה ומרור להראות לכולנה,‏
   ולא כן לבישרא דלפסחא דוכרנא,‏
   כוסו יניף לשבע הודאות או שמונה,‏
   עד ברכת גאולת עדת מי מנה,‏
   הלל המצרי להנעימו ברינה,‏
   ברכת המצות אין כאן לשננה,‏
   מקדים זבח לדבח חייס וחנינה,‏
   להודות שיר חדש ולא כנקבה בלשונה,‏
   יינו יברך גם בכוס תניינא.‏
   **ר**חיצת ידים מצוה לעשות ככה,‏
   פרוסה בתוך השלימה להניחה ולתומכה,‏
   בוצע בשלימה המוציא ולא מכל אחת כזית בסמיכה,‏
   לכסכוסי מרורים בכזית ובברכה,‏
   משקען בחרוסת דקיהויא ודסמיכא,‏
   ולשהויי ביה לא אריכה,‏
   דאיתעבד לטיבול בלילתו רכה,‏
   ואין כאן זיקוק הטייה ונמיכה,‏
   מצה שלישית ומרור בכריכה,‏
   בלי ברכה אבל טיבול צריכה,‏
   ואף מסיב כדרך אנשי נסיכה,‏
   גומר מאז סעודה לכל צורכה,‏
   ומפטיר במצה שבשמלה כרוכה,‏
   קודם חצות אכילה זו נערכה,‏
   כל מיני טעם ומתיקה להשליכה,‏
   מדיח ידיו מזוהמות מלח המהפכה,‏
   בכוס יפה לברך על המזון כהלכה.‏
   **א-ל** עליון לשבחו ולגמור הלולו,‏
   מלחתום ביהללוך ישמור מילולו,‏
   הלל הגדול ונשמת כל חי כלו,‏
   וחותם בשבח זה והמצרי בכללו,‏
   מוסיף בשבחות הא-ל כרוב גדלו,‏
   להזכיר רוב ניסיו וגבורת חילו,‏
   כי לו נאה במלוכה לעלו,‏
   יברך על הכוס ברכה הראויה לו,‏
   דברכה מעין שלש מכוס זה מהחדילו,‏
   מהרה יופיע צור ישראל וגואלו.‏
   (R' Yisrael Iserlan ben Pesachya Ashkenazi, author of the Terumas HaDeshen; the bolded letters indicate the beginning of stanzas, and they spell out ישראל)

Comment: At some point these are just Piyutim, just like those said on Shabbat HaGadol in Shacharit.