# Yahatz as a step in the Seder

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

When did Yahatz, as a ceremonial breaking of a specific piece of matzah, become a part of the Seder? In the Gemara (Pesachim 115b), there's a discussion of what it means for matzah to be "lehem oni", and there it mentions that one of the connections is that just as a poor person only has a piece of a loaf, so too the matzah is only a piece. This is only one of the possible reasons given.

How was that explanation chosen as *the* reason, and how/when did that turn into what's done nowadays?

Comment: When else do you suggest tearing a Matza and putting aside for Afikoman?

Comment: @DoubleAA why assume that we start the seder with three whole instead of breaking it as part of the setup?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm not assuming that. I'm asking: does he have a better suggestion? A question of "why do X" is much stronger if there is some better option than X. Otherwise, you could just ask "why do Y" to any Y suggested in place of X, and you end up nowhere.

Answer (score 4):

It’s already mentioned as a distinct part of the Seder in the *piyyut* for *shabbat hagadol* composed by [R. Yosef Tuv Elem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Samuel_Bonfils) (980 - 1050).

After instructing that one eats *karpas*, he [writes](http://mobile.tora.ws/html/2220223-6.html):

> וְכַד אָכִיל יֶחֱצֶה אַחַת מִשָׁלֹשׁ מַצוֹת וְאֵין בְּרָכָה עִמָּהּ. מַחֲצָה בִקְעָרָה וּמַחֲצָה בְשֻׁלְחָן לְהָשִׂימָה
>
> And when one eats he should break one of the three matzot without reciting a blessing; half is left on the plate and half is placed in the table.

He then goes on to describe removing the cooked foods from the plate, reciting *ha lachma anya*, pouring the second cup, and asking *mah nishtanah*.

---

In terms of why it’s done this way (rather than say preparing a broken matzah before the Seder starts) I conjecture that it’s done in order to prompt the children present to ask questions.

Consider the description found in the *piyyut*. We’ve made *kiddush* and eaten an appetizer. We’ve brought the food and bread to the table. It looks like the main meal is about to start. We then break the bread. But instead of eating it, we put it to one side. We then start taking food off the table, and pour another cup of wine. All this should hopefully prompt the children to ask for an explanation of what’s going on.

Comment: it's also in basically all the medieval mnemonics https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81655/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting. Are any of those older than this?

Comment: I don't think so (though possibly some of those mnemonics could be much older than the sources which cite them)

Comment: It's odd that it seems so concretely part of the Seder by then when Rav Saadiah Gaon makes no mention of it in his description of the Seder.

Comment: @AvramLevitt Does R Tuv Elem mentioning it really indicate it is "such a concrete part of the Seder"?

Comment: I was referring to it being in all the medieval mnemonics. It seems weird that it would appear suddenly without any source of where it was invented and who invented it.

Comment: @AvramLevitt Could be that it developed in Eretz Yisrael or early Ashkenaz, as opposed to Bavel which would explain why Rasag (and Rambam) don’t mention it.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Rambam’s haggadah does not have this step; 
he breaks his matza at Motzi-Matza. See https://www.torahweb.org/torah/2009/moadim/rsac_pesach2.html