The simanei haseder (TOC of the seder)
Why was the simanei haseder created? Is there any real significance to them other than just being a table of contents? And Why do we chant or sing it at the start of the seder?

So the children should ask

Which one are you referring to? There's well over a dozen of them https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81654/759

What do you mean by "real significance" to them? People have certainly written many divrei torah about whatever poem they had in front of them.

due to the fact that so many were composed there is clearly a real reason as to why we need it...@DoubleAA

Ya, it's because the Passover Seder is long and has lots of steps. Sometimes people get confused what comes next! They didn't have dozens of printed hagadot in every house. It's by far the most complicated long obscure ritual regularly done by individuals in their home.

The Chida wrote many interpretations of the classic simanei haseder used today.
